# Application killed when Android Crop intent is launched

Tags: android, android-intent, libgdx

So I'm developing a LibGDX Application and I have the user  choose an image and then proceed to crop it .
I get image path and then I  try to start the crop intent but my app crashes with error
I enter the crop screen with the right image but my app is already killed and when I click save I return to my homescreen :

```
07-11 22:26:24.142: E/AndroidGraphics(8692): waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

Some Code:

MainActivity:

```
String userImagePath = null;
AndroidGalleryOpener opener;
Uri imageUri;
public static final int SELECT_CROP_CODE = 2;



    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                switch (requestCode) {
                case AndroidGalleryOpener.SELECT_IMAGE_CODE:
                    imageUri = data.getData();
                    this.userImagePath = getPath(imageUri);
                    Gdx.app.log("AndroidGalleryOpener", "Image path is " + userImagePath);
                    opener.setImageResult(userImagePath);

                    //////Cropping starts ;
                    System.out.println("Cropper called");
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                        intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
                        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                        intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
                        intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
                        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                        //intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true); 

                            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_CROP_CODE);

                    break;
                case SELECT_CROP_CODE:
                    //get the returned data
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    //get the cropped bitmap
                    Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    Gdx.app.log("Croper", "Croper on activity result ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }


            }
```

Logcat:

```
 07-11 22:26:07.306: I/AndroidGraphics(8692): coverage sampling: (false)
07-11 22:26:07.316: I/AndroidGraphics(8692): Managed meshes/app: { }
07-11 22:26:07.316: I/AndroidGraphics(8692): Managed textures/app: { }
07-11 22:26:07.316: I/AndroidGraphics(8692): Managed shaders/app: { }
07-11 22:26:07.316: I/AndroidGraphics(8692): Managed buffers/app: { }
07-11 22:26:07.646: I/dalvikvm-heap(8692): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.484MB for 4162562-byte allocation
07-11 22:26:12.411: I/dalvikvm-heap(8692): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.791MB for 4162562-byte allocation
07-11 22:26:13.932: I/AndroidGraphics(8692): paused
07-11 22:26:13.942: I/AndroidInput(8692): sensor listener tear down
07-11 22:26:13.982: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.022: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.022: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:14.032: W/ApplicationPackageManager(8692): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-11 22:26:15.704: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8692): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-11 22:26:20.108: I/AndroidGalleryOpener(8692): Image path is /storage/emulated/0/Download/Agent_Thompson.jpg
07-11 22:26:20.108: I/System.out(8692): Cropper called
07-11 22:26:20.128: I/SensorManagerA(8692): getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 1
07-11 22:26:20.128: I/SensorManagerA(8692): getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 2
07-11 22:26:20.128: I/AndroidInput(8692): sensor listener setup
07-11 22:26:24.142: E/AndroidGraphics(8692): waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
07-11 22:26:24.142: I/Process(8692): Sending signal. PID: 8692 SIG: 9
```